# Include a php class -the old way- on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I need a fast way to test a code, please I know is not the best practice, but is there a way to load a class on a symfony controller without having to add namespaces, proxy class and autoloader stuff?

I tried:

```
public function singlepagestatsAction($id, $pid, $group) { 
    include '/var/www/web/welcomestuff/scripts/ga/gapi.class.php';
            $ga = new gapi('email','password');
```

Inside my controller, but when i execute it; `Fatal error: Class 'Done\PunctisBundle\Controller\gapi' not found in /var/www/src/Done/PunctisBundle/Controller/BrandController.php on line 630`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add \ before class name

> $ga = new \gapi('email','password');

Comment: in your controller u set namespace so php basically add this namespace to classes (u can use classes without adding use in same folder :) )

Char \ say to use use "namespace" from begin. It's hard to explain for me, better read on php doc about it http://www.php.net/manual/pl/language.namespaces.basics.php